# Angular Template Driven Form with Material inputs resets itself upon initialization

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, angular-forms

I am working on a fairly straight forward template driven form (thats why I am not using reactive approach) with material form fields in my application.

The required behavior is that the form is shown only when the user clicks on a button until which point it is hidden using the *ngIf structural directive.

I would like to set some default values for the input fields for the user to see when the form is shown. But, when the user clicks on the button, i see the form is getting reset before it is presented to the user thereby getting rid of the default values specified.

the stackBlitz to replicate the scenario is [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-template-driven-forms?file=app/input-overview-example.html)

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you must be doing a two way binding for the default value

in your Component

```
export class InputOverviewExample {
  isShown: boolean = false;

  test:String = "asdasd";
}
```

And in your Template

```
<textarea matInput placeholder="Leave a comment" value="some comments about the food" [(ngModel)]="test" name="comments"></textarea>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: hi jenno, sure i could use two way binding or one way binding [ngModel]="test". But, wouldnt that defeat the whole purpose of having the **value**  attribute on the input tag? I was trying to leverage the value attribute.